# When I assign InnerText to string varible All all enter characters removed

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I use htmlagilitypack.
This is part of my code to get innertext from single node.

```
var edit = outDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//textarea[@id='wpTextbox1']//text()");
String _edit;
_edit = edit.InnerText.ToString().Trim();
```

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pv3A.jpg)

When I write _edit to text file , All texts are bound(all enter characters removed).

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv0eq.jpg)

I want texts with enter characters.
How  can I fix this?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Instead of `.InnerText` try `.Value` or `.InnerXml` or `.OuterXml` to see if any of them has the new line characters encoded.

Comment: just Outerhtml and Innerhtml exsist. tryed thats but no diffrent.

Comment: Does removing the `.Trim()` fix the problem? If you need to trim whitespace from the beginning of the string, you could use `TrimStart()` instead.

Comment: I want to my output of picture 2 be similar to picture 1. that's mean is my output file's texts have enter character between lines. i test your offer but result didn't any change.

Answer (score 0):

HTML text that you receive contains the character "\n" as newline. Meanwhile, Windows uses two symbols "\r\n" for this purpose. Therefore, the Notepad displays the text in this way.

You need to make the change:

```
string _edit = edit.InnerText.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
```